# Embedding PHP within AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

First of all, let me supply what I'm disposing with in this scenario:

**index.php**

```
<script text='type/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').click(load);
    });

    function load(){
        $.ajax({
            data:<?php header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');echo 'Ok'; ?>
        }).done(function(data){
            $('#content').append(data);
        }
    }
</script>

<select id='load'>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
```

I need whenever the select menu is clicked, a PHP code snippet to be executed. In this case let's I need the string ***'Ok'*** to be executed (just an example so as to see how it would work). However I'm not quite confident as far as Ajax is concerned but I'm certain the following is the issue:

```
data:<?php header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');echo 'Ok'; ?>
```

I do not prefer to use **url:''** and redirect to a page where the PHP I want to execute is located. I need it all in the ***index.php*** file. As well as that I expect this to be done with Ajax because I need the requests being asynchronous so that the page won't be refreshed.

In fact I'm developing a database modifier and I need to list all tables from a corresponding database and I need to validate that through Ajax as you might guess. So I need whenever a database has been chosen to list the tables from within it. I'm posting all this in case it may help.

[image: Code structure]

*Thank you in advance for any answers and possible solutions!*

Comment: FYI: This won't work => `exit;echo 'Ok';` for one thing. When the script hits `exit` it's basically **out the door** (:::ELVIS::: has left the building), nothing else is executed after that, therefore the echo never takes place. Whether it be Ajax or just plain PHP.

Comment: Yes. However, this is not related to the actual subject. Thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: Related or not, it's not a good pseudo-example. *(You're welcome)*

Comment: Either ways the whole line is invalid as of syntax. So I need to do what @Alex Dumitru said and send the request to this page via **data:**. That is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed PHP into javascript. You will have to use AJAX to load the data from another PHP page.

Something like this:

```
<script text='type/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#load').click(load);
    });

    function load(){
        $.ajax({
            url: http://www.example.com/phppage.php,
            type: POST,
            data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        }).done(function(data){
            $('#content').append(data);

        }
    }
</script>

<select id='load'>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
```

You can read more on the [documentation page for jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: While it is certainly arguable as to whether it is advisable to embed PHP into JavaScript it is definitely possible to do so.

Comment: It is possible when the Javascript is in scope of the PHP. But however I mentioned I need not use another file for the execution.

Comment: Then you can send the AJAX request to the same page and set conditions based on the requests.

Comment: That is what I am asking for.

Comment: The script that I posted does that. You just have to change the URL with your current URL. Then create a PHP condition that checks if a certain POST request is sent and execute your function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,there is no way to Embedding PHP within AJAX .PHP is the language which running on the server, and ajax is just the javascript running on your browser. PHP cant't running on the browser. But your brower can't send http requerst to the PHP server and get the reply from it .So, like Alex Dumitru answered .You need a php page like 'phppage.php' the example which Alex Dumitru mentioned to get your request via ajax.Then you can finsh other functions.